# A problem on container assignment operations mentioned in C++ Primer

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, assign

In "C++ Primer" Section 9.2, Table 9.4, there is an item about `seq.assign(b, c)` saying

> The iterators b and e must not refer to elements in seq.

However, when I try to use `seq.begin()` and `seq.end()` to assign back to `seq`, it is ok. So I feel confused about this item, or I misunderstand it.

The following code works successfully and outputs `2 3 4`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> b{1, 2, 3, 4};
    b.assign(b.begin() + 1, b.end());
    std::cout << b[0] << ' ' << b[1] << ' ' << b[2];
    return 0;
}
```

I know `assign()` will invalidate iterators into the left-hand container, but what happened in the implementation? Did the destruction happen before the assignment, or after it?

Comment: I haven't looked at your concrete code, but the statement is clear: you must not. The fact that any single example shows no bad behavior is not at all a proof that things might not go horribly wrong with other inputs, or on another version of your compiler, of with a different implementation of the standard library.

Comment: The fact that somehting compiles or seems to work in C++ doesn't mean the program is correct.

Comment: _"Did the deconstruction happen before the assignment or after it?"_ The issue is here. In fact, the `assign()` iterates on given interval to fill the vector, so it iterates on data while modifying them! Deconstruction and assignment are interleaved, all is possible, **this is an Undefined Behavior**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, and reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign, it's clear that you are causing *undefined behaviour*. That means anything might happen - it might just work, it might crash, or it might output incorrect data, or worse things. It's not said that running the same program two times will even produce the same result of undefined behaviour.

So, yes, showing a toy example that things work is worth nothing in terms of correct code, and your code is buggy.

When preconditions on the input of a function are as clearly stated as here, you must not deviate, or you will get unreliable and thus broken behavior.